# Targeting an input type within a div#

Tags: css

Trying to style the last box or input type in this case using Jetpack in Wordpress.

I have tried:

```
#subscribe-submit > input[type="submit"]::last-of-type {
#subscribe-submit > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(6)
```

Is there anything else that might work?

**Here is the code**

```
<p id="subscribe-submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="sub-type" value="widget">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_fragment" value="blog_subscription-2">
    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="8e7bd4e874">                      
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget">
</p>
```

Comment: Why not just `#subscribe-submit > input[type="submit"]`

Comment: There are many possible answers to this question, you already got two, so i'm going to tell you what you did wrong. You selected `input[type="submit"]:nth-child(6)` which would choose the 6th `input` with type `submit`, but you only have one, either one of these would work perfectly: `input:nth-child(6)` or `input[type="submit"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply tagget it with `input[name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget"]` like this:

```css
#subscribe-submit > input[name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget"] {padding:50px;}
```

```html
<p id="subscribe-submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
  <input type="hidden" name="source" value="http://mvcframe.com/stockley/events/">
  <input type="hidden" name="sub-type" value="widget">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_fragment" value="blog_subscription-2">
  <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="8e7bd4e874">
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for select last input element:

```
#subscribe-submit > input[type="submit"]:last-child{
    color: green;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wirojahore/edit?html,css,output)

**Update:**

For use last element with any type use this:

```
#subscribe-submit > :last-child{ ...
```

Comment: This is redundant code, and don't just post code without any comment.

Comment: @Tarekis redundant code? what's ur mean? there is no comment. it's css selector for ID

Comment: `:last-child` is redundant, there is only one `type=submit` tag. Also the last piece of code should be `*:last-child`. Regarding the comment i meant, when you answer, do not just post code, but add at least a one-liner of explanation, "This will do that" isn't really hard to type.

Comment: he says: `Trying to style the last box or ...`. This code use for all type of elements even if does not input.

Comment: Your code selects the `last` child that is has `type` `submit`, making it redundant. The `last` input has `type=submit`, so you select by two identifiers the tag has. See you are combining two selecetors: [last](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/qp94fzh7/) and [type](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/qp94fzh7/4/). If you do not understand what redundant code is, please look it up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following css :

```
#subscribe-submit input[type="submit"]:last-child
{ color: green; }
```